# Expand Collapse functionality breaks jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project I'm using Vertical-Accordion-Menu-Plugin-For-jQuery-Nav-Accordion that allows me to make parent links clickable. I have made some minor changes to jQuery to make it keyboard accessible. Everything looks good besides one little thing. When I expand all levels and then close parent's container, sub-level items are not longer showing expand/collapse button. For some reasons it breaks. https://jsfiddle.net/webIra7/mvtf6zve/

```js
/* Nav Accordion Plugin v1.1.2
************************************/
(function($){
 $.fn.navAccordion = function(options, callback){
  this.each(function(){
   
   //Options
   var settings = $.extend({
    expandButtonText : "+", //Text inside of expand button
    collapseButtonText: "-",  //Text inside of collapse button
    selectedExpand: "true",   //Expand the selected channel
    selectedClass: "selected",  //Class that will be used to detect the currently selected channel - this will check the "parentElement" for this class (the parent <li> by default)
    multipleLevels: "true",  //Apply accordion to all levels - setting this to false will apply the accordion only to the first level
    buttonWidth: "20%",  //Width of accordion expand/collapse button as a percentage or pixels
    buttonPosition: "right",  //Position of button - 'right' is default - you can also choose 'left'
    slideSpeed: "fast",   //Speed of slide animation - "fast", "slow", or number in milliseconds such as 500
    parentElement: "li",  //Parent element type, class or ID - you don't need to change this if you're using a ul > li > ul pattern
    childElement: "ul",   //Child element type, class or ID - you don't need to change this if you're using a ul > li > ul pattern
    headersOnly: false,  //False is default - setting to true will make any link with sub-nav behave as if it were set to header only, making the link inaccessible - this option is useful if you are using the plugin for a non-navigation area 
    headersOnlyCheck: false, // False is default - set to true to apply the accordion only to links that are set as "header only" (have no href)
    delayLink: false,  //Delay following the href of links until after the accordion the has expanded
    delayAmount: null //Time in milliseconds to delay before following href - will use "slideSpeed" by default if nothing else is set
   }, options);
   
   var container = this,
   //Multiple levels variable
    multi = settings.multipleLevels ? '': ' > ' + settings.childElement + ' > ';
    
   //Add class to container
   $(container)
    .addClass('accordion-nav');
   
   //Apply has-subnav class to lis with uls - also add accordion buttons with styles
   $(multi + settings.parentElement, container).each(function(){
    if ( ($(this).contents(settings.childElement).length > 0 
     && settings.headersOnlyCheck == false) || (!($('> a', this).attr('href')) 
     && settings.headersOnlyCheck == true) )  
    {
     //Apply Class and styles to parent item
     $(this).addClass('has-subnav')
      .css('position', 'relative')
       .find('>a')
        .css('margin-' + settings.buttonPosition, settings.buttonWidth);
     
     //Add expand button elements
     $(' > ' + settings.childElement, this)
      .before('<span class="accordion-btn-wrap"><a href="#"><span class="accordion-btn accordion-collapsed">' 
      + settings.expandButtonText + '</span><a href="#"><span class="accordion-btn accordion-expanded">' 
      + settings.collapseButtonText + '</span></a></span></a>');
      
     //Apply Styles to expand button
     $('.accordion-btn-wrap', this)
      .css({
       'width': settings.buttonWidth, 
       'position': 'absolute', 
       'top': 0, 
       'text-align': 'center', 
       'cursor': 'pointer', 
       'display': 'inline-block'
      })
      .css(settings.buttonPosition, 0);
     $('.accordion-btn ', this)
      .css({
       'display': 'inline-block', 
       'width': '100%'
      });
     $('.accordion-expanded', this)
      .css('display', 'none');
    }
    
    //Apply styles to <a> tags that are set to header only
    if (!($('> a', this).attr('href')) || settings.headersOnly){
     $(this)
      .addClass('accordion-header-only')
       .find('.accordion-btn-wrap')
        .css({
         'width': '100%', 
         'text-align': settings.buttonPosition
        })
        .find('.accordion-btn ')
         .css({
          'width': settings.buttonWidth, 
          'text-align': 'center'
         });
    }
    
    //Delay Link Mode
    if (settings.delayLink && !settings.headersOnly) {
     var currentThis = this,
      speed = settings.delayAmount != null ? settings.delayAmount : settings.slideSpeed;
     if (speed == "fast") {
      speed = 200;
     } else if (speed == "slow") {
      speed = 600;
     }
     $('> a', currentThis).on('click',function(e){
      if (!$('> .accordion-btn-wrap', currentThis).hasClass("accordion-active")) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var href = $(this).attr('href');
       clickToggle($('> .accordion-btn-wrap', currentThis));
       //Go to link after delay
       setTimeout(function(){
        window.location = href;
       }, speed)
      }
     })
    }
    
   });
   
   var selectedNavAccordion = $(settings.parentElement + '.' + settings.selectedClass + ' > .accordion-btn-wrap', container);
   
   //Debounced Button height event listener
   var buttonheightResize = debounce(function(){
    //Run button height
    buttonheight();
    //Expand Selected Channel
    expandSelected();
   }, 250);
   $(window).on('resize', buttonheightResize);
   
   //Set button heights
   buttonheight();
   
   //Expand Selected Channel
   expandSelected();
   
   //On click function
   $(container).on('click', '.accordion-btn-wrap', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    clickToggle(this);
   });
   
   //Callback
   if (typeof callback == "function") {
    callback();
   }
   
   
   /* Functions 
   *******************************/
    //Click Toggle function
    function clickToggle(element) {
     var nextChild = $(element).next(settings.childElement),
      currentExpandBtn = $('.accordion-expanded', element),
      currentCollapseBtn = $('.accordion-collapsed', element),
      parentObj = $(element).closest(settings.parentElement);
     if (nextChild.is(':visible')) {
      nextChild
       .slideUp(settings.slideSpeed);
      $(element)
       .removeClass('accordion-active');
      currentExpandBtn
       .css('display', 'none');
      currentCollapseBtn
       .css('display', 'inline-block');
      parentObj.add(parentObj.siblings('.active')).add(parentObj.find('.active')).removeClass('active');
     } else {
      $(element).closest(settings.childElement).find('.accordion-active')
       .removeClass('accordion-active')
       .next(settings.childElement)
        .slideUp(settings.slideSpeed).prev()
        .find('.accordion-expanded')
         .css('display', 'none')
         .parent().find('.accordion-collapsed')
          .css('display', 'inline-block');
      parentObj.add(parentObj.siblings('.active')).add(parentObj.find('.active')).removeClass('active');
      $(element)
       .addClass('accordion-active');
      nextChild
       .slideToggle(settings.slideSpeed);
      currentExpandBtn
       .css('display', 'inline-block');
      currentCollapseBtn
       .css('display', 'none');
      parentObj.addClass('active');
     }
    }
    
    //Expand Selected Channel Function
    function expandSelected(){
     if(settings.selectedExpand){
      if(!settings.headersOnlyCheck){
      selectedNavAccordion.find('.accordion-expanded')
       .css('display', 'inline-block');
      selectedNavAccordion.find('.accordion-collapsed')
       .css('display', 'none');
      selectedNavAccordion.addClass('accordion-active')
       .next(settings.childElement)
        .css('display', 'block');
      selectedNavAccordion.closest(settings.parentElement)
       .addClass('active');
      } else {
       $(settings.parentElement + '.' + settings.selectedClass + ' > ' + settings.childElement, container)
        .css('display', 'block');
        $(settings.parentElement + '.' + settings.selectedClass).addClass('active');
      }
     }
    }
   
    //Accordion Button Height Function
    function buttonheight(){
     $('.accordion-btn', container).each(function(){
      //Show uls so heights are calculated correctly
      $(settings.parentElement + '.has-subnav > ' + settings.childElement, container)
       .css('display', 'block');
      
      //Calculate and set heights
      var parentItem = $(this).closest(settings.parentElement),
       lineheight =  $('> a', parentItem).innerHeight();
      $(this)
       .css({'line-height': lineheight + 'px', 'height': lineheight});
      
      //Hide uls under lis and reset expand/collapse buttons
      $(settings.parentElement + ((settings.headersOnlyCheck) ? ' ' : '.has-subnav > ') + settings.childElement, container)
       .css('display', 'none');
      $('.accordion-expanded')
       .css('display', 'none');
      $('.accordion-collapsed')
       .css('display', 'inline-block');
     })
    }  
    //Debounce function
    function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
     var timeout;
     return function() {
      var context = this, args = arguments;
      var later = function() {
       timeout = null;
       if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
      };
      var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
      if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
     };
    }; 
  });
 }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I see that both the collapse and expand buttons have inline style display:none. I am researching to see what is causing this and will update If I find the cause

Comment: thanks, I'll look at it as well

Comment: can you post or link to  the original code before you altered it? I see the version number but its not immediately apparent where to find the original file.

Comment: That is the link to the original plugin http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Vertical-Accordion-Menu-Plugin-For-jQuery-Nav-Accordion.html

Comment: I updated my answer with a  fix.  could not post updated fiddle due to issues with jsfidlle at this moment

Answer (score 0):

the error is related to the line below not finding the '.accordion-collapsed' element, due searching for parent(), whic assumes a specific dom structure. 
using  .closest() is more flexible. 
one way to fix this is to replace

```
.parent().find('.accordion-collapsed').css('display', 'inline-block');
```

with

```
.closest('ul').find('.accordion-collapsed').css('display', 'inline-block');
```

line is taken from this section:

```
$(element).closest(settings.childElement).find('.accordion-active')
                            .removeClass('accordion-active')
                            .next(settings.childElement)
                                .slideUp(settings.slideSpeed).prev()
                                .find('.accordion-expanded')
                                    .css('display', 'none')
                                    .parent().find('.accordion-collapsed')
                                        .css('display', 'inline-block');
```

Comment: I was able to find another fix as well, I just simply removed an extra <a> tag from my JavaScript. So that expanded button doesn't get focus //Add expand button elements
     $(' > ' + settings.childElement, this)
      .before('<span class="accordion-btn-wrap"><a href="#"><span class="accordion-btn accordion-collapsed">' 
      + settings.expandButtonText + '</span><span class="accordion-btn accordion-expanded">' 
      + settings.collapseButtonText + '</span></a></span>');

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue, I just needed to remove an extra  tag from my JavaScript.

```
//Add expand button elements
$(' > ' + settings.childElement, this)
.before('<span class="accordion-btn-wrap"><a href="#"><span class="accordion-btn accordion-collapsed">' 
+ settings.expandButtonText + '</span><span class="accordion-btn accordion-expanded">' 
+ settings.collapseButtonText + '</span></a></span>');
```

I have updated my js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/webIra7/mvtf6zve/5/